# show that $\lim_{ h\to 0} (a^h-1)/h=\ln(a)$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I would like to show:

$$\lim_{ h\to 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h}=\ln(a)$$

So I've got two questions:

1) Find the value of $\lim_{h\to 0}(a^h-1)/h$. You don't know that the answer is $\ln(a)$, you can't guess, so you have to derive it without using it. You can only use the $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$ definition for $e$. The definition for $\ln(a)=x$ is $e^x=a$.

2) Show that $\lim_{h\to 0}(a^h-1)/h$ and $\ln(a)$ is the same by whatever means.

Comment: However, you need to have a *definition* for $a^h$. Which do you have?

Comment: It appears that you are taking exponentiation with real powers for granted. In such questions it is important that we provide the definition of $a^b$ and also $e^x$ (without which your definition for $\log(a) $ won't work).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Substituting $$a^h-1=m$$ so $$h=\frac{\ln(m+1)}{\ln(a)}$$ and we get
$$\frac{a^h-1}{h}=\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(m+1)^{1/m}}$$ Since $h$ tends to zero, $m$ tends to zero.

Comment: but $$\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(m+1)^{1/m}}$$ when m tends to zero isn't ln(a)? wolframalpha gave me infinity*ln(a) when i put it in. did i miss something?

Comment: The limit $$\lim_{m\to 0}(1+m)^{1/m}=e$$!!!

Comment: So you will get $$\ln(a)$$

Comment: oh i think i get, just gonna go through it a few times, thank you !

Comment: Nice that i could help you!

Answer (score 0):

Use L'Hôpital's Rule:

The prerequisites are met since $$\lim_{h\to 0}(a^h-1)=\lim_{h\to 0}(h)=0$$
So we apply:
$$\frac{d}{dh}(a^h-1)=a^h\ln(a)$$
$$\frac{d}{dh}(h)=1$$

$$\to\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}(a^h\ln a)=\ln(a)$$